# Type systems understanding problems

Tags: type-theory

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this kind of a question, but here goes:

I'm doing my own reading of the Principles of Program Analysis book, and i'm having trouble understanding some priciples from Chapter 5 - Type and Effect Systems.

In the book (page 286) there is an example:

[image]

I can not understand, why do they start with the expression fun<sub>F</sub> f x => ... 
Is this maybe **guessing** the values of the types of the bound variables **f** and **x**, we just assume that **f** is of type function that takes a function and returns a function, and that **x** is of type function (because it seems about right)?

After that we have to determine the type of the function body, so we move to f (fn<sub>Y</sub> y => y). From the assumed types, we infer the type **f** (the top bottom rule in the image), and then we move to: fn<sub>Y</sub> y => y, and it is streightforward that the type of that expression is **t -> t** (a function that returns the same type that it was given).

[image]

Now that we know this, we can determine the type of the function application  f (fn<sub>Y</sub> y => y) as **t -> t**.

Then again we move up to determine the type of **fun<sub>F</sub> ...** which accoring to the rules for recursive functions is streight-forward (the same type as for **f** in the assumed typed enviroment)..

Then we move to the in body: g (fn<sub>Z</sub> => z). g's type has already been determined immediatly above, so we move to fn<sub>Z</sub> => z which is the same as for fn<sub>Y</sub>. And in the end we get that the whole expression has the type: **t -> t**.

What i'm asking is: is this the correct trail of thought? Or i'm i missing the point somewhere?

I'm not sure about the guessing part, why did we start where we did, why not more simply with variable y or somewhere else? The rest of the chapter heavily depends on the proper understanding of these concepts, and i would like to understand this.

In general, I would be grateful if somebody could point me out to a book or something that, in more details explains type systems.

Thank you!